# Python mmap /dev/port

Tags: python, linux, mmap, ioports

Is it possible to mmap /dev/port?  I'm getting 'No such device' when I try.

```
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:06:09) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import mmap
>>> os.open('/dev/port', os.O_RDWR|os.O_NDELAY)
3
>>> mapfd = mmap.mmap(3, 0xfff)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
mmap.error: [Errno 19] No such device
>>>
```

I've been able to mmap a regular file with the same options.

Comment: What would be the meaning of mmaping `/dev/port`? mmaping `/dev/mem` makes sense, `/dev/port` not so.

Comment: @ninjalj it would just allow me to write directly to an ioport addr without having to seek before every read/write.

Comment: maybe using pwrite with ctypes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Errno 19 is listed as "No such device" (Linux), or "Operation not supported by device" (FreeBSD).

Looking at the source code for `/dev/port` in `drivers/char/mem.c`, especially the `struct file_operations`, you'll [see](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=drivers/char/mem.c;h=d6e9d081c8b101169eb4f032ee394b97f07516cd;hb=HEAD):

```
770 #ifdef CONFIG_DEVPORT
771 static const struct file_operations port_fops = {
772         .llseek         = memory_lseek,
773         .read           = read_port,
774         .write          = write_port,
775         .open           = open_port,
776 };
777 #endif
```

This device doesn't support mmap. Only opening, seeking, reading and writing.

Comment: +1 for pointing to the kernel source. My kernel-fu is less than awesome.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, `/dev/port` isn't `mmap`-able.  But seeing as how you're using python -- let's harness the true power of dynamic types!  Why not create an `mmap`-like object which supports the same interface, but uses `lseek` underneath?